# Get location where npm packages installed

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc

I've hit an error when trying to build my typescript code. Did some checking and found this issue. Any idea where can I get source location for `npm run tsc`?

[image]

Edit: add result for `npm list -g`

```
➜  ~ npm list -g
/home/hakeem/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib
├── npm@7.7.6
├── typescript@4.4.2
└── which@2.0.2
```

Comment: Does the command `npm root` helps you in any way?

Comment: @I'mUser17781575 `npm root` does not do the works as i install `typescript` globally. running `npm root` on `~/hakeem` only return `/home/hakeem/node_modules` which not exists

Comment: I also found out that my `npm run tsc --version` return my `npm --version`. I've try to remove nvm (delete `~/.nvm`,`~/.npm`, source line in `~.zshrc`), after install it again same issue occur